# Domain name without WWW is not working on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, dns

In the image are my current Hosted zone details on AWS. When I visit `www.giftforhilt.com` it works but when I visit `giftforhilt.com` it does not work.

How can I fix this?

[image: Domain configuration]

Comment: Can you post more details? Which web server are you using? If you can also post the server configuration that would be helpful.

Comment: Can you post more information what you mean by does not work?

Comment: It does not work meaning the site does not load up

Comment: Both resolve to the same IP so securty groups wouldn't be the cause of this. Are you listening for a specific hostname on your server?

Answer (score 0):

Can you add another A record using the record name giftforhit.com, the same way that you have done for [www.giftforhit.com](http://www.giftforhit.com). just now use without www. And one thing is better when you give the ttl(time to leave) 60 where you did 3600. Then, lets see what happens.